# CSS3 a link hover transition

Tags: css, transform, href, transition

Have the following class

```
.home-cards a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
 }

.home-cards a:hover {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: red;
}
```

Am trying to add a transition/transform to either the font-size or color in order to make the hover effect less jerky. Have been unable to find anything that discusses those two elements in regards transition. Any help would be appreciated as this is a non-commercial project for big Sis's recipe site ... yeah the net needs another one of those but in her defense non-gluton recipes only.

Sorry forgot to mention the font-size is 12px and font-color is a sort of grey if not hovered over

Answer (score 0):

I just added these lines and hope it helps you:

1. font-size: 12px; (To set the font size)
2. transition: .5s font-size, 1s color; (Means 0.5 seconds to changing the font-size and 1s to changing the color of the link)
3. color: grey; (To change the text color)
4. text-decoration: none; (To remove the underline of the link)

```css
.home-cards a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    transition: .5s font-size, 1s color;
    color: grey;
    text-decoration: none;
 }

.home-cards a:hover {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-cards">

    <a href="">Test</a>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose which properties you want the transform to apply to.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

```css
a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: grey;
  transition: font-size 0.5s ease, color 0.5s ease;
}

a:hover {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: red;
  transition: font-size 0.5s ease, color 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">My Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a different element tag inside of your anchor tag for example:

```
<a href="#"><p style="display: inline; margin: 0;">test</p></a>
```

Try different css selector:

```
.home-card a:hover p{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: red; 
}
```

You may want to remove extra margin from p tag...and make it display inline since p tag is a block-level element.